# Technique to cause compile time error if members are added to class in C++

Tags: c++, reflection

Let's say you have some POD which contain multiple public members. You also have some classes which serialize and deserialize these objects from various sources. Are there any coding techniques, other than unit tests, which would make sure that when you add a member to the class, you update any additional code that needs to know about the added field.

i.e. I'd love a technique that would cause compile time errors until all code was updated to handle the new fields.

Comment: This is very related to serialization. I think I can find a pretty good answer by Yakk that discusses a technique to export data members as a tuple. Until we really get reflection, though, probably not possible without being a bit inconvenient.

Comment: You can make 1 central list of members [like I did here](https://github.com/Toeger/SCE/blob/b38474f7887c7bcdb71295fff24f4ebd25e0b6bc/logic/tool.h#L28) and have the rest of the code use that list. Alternatively you may be able to auto-generate that list using [magic get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Comment: If you use some library as boost hana and `BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT`, you might write your code using reflection.

Comment: by POC, do you mean POD ?

Comment: BTW, why not adding some compile-time versioning logic for your pod ?

Comment: Have the classes perform self-serialization via polymorphism. That way, if you add new members to a class, you can update the serialization code for the same class. Code outside of the classes shouldn't know or care how the classes serialize themselves, just so long as they do it correctly

Answer (score 1):

There's no reflection in C++.

But a solution, which also has the attractive property that it doesn't pollute your compiled code, is to use a `static_assert(sizeof(YourType) == x, <message>)` where `x` is a hard-coded constant, contingent on your compiler.

Any member added to `YourType` will change `sizeof`, and induce a compile time failure.

(There *might* be some instances where this doesn't work if a new member occupies the space that was previously end-of-structure padding. Try the approach first with your compiler to see if this is feasible.)

Comment: I'm sure we could brainstorm other contrived ways to break that. Like adding a new member to a union. Or changing the type of a pointer.

Comment: @AndyG: I only purport to address "add a member to the class".

Comment: Not bad. Certainly is a reasonable bit of protection.

Comment: If POC = POD (or even aggregate) then there's reflecion since c++11

Answer (score 1):

from **c++17** on, you could exploit *structured bindings*: you add a convention to your codebase that whenever a function requires the POD to be *the* up-to-date version, *that* function should access the pod via structured bindings:

```
struct A { int a,b,c; };

void foo( A& the_pod )
{
  auto& [a,b,c] = the_pod;

  // ... use a,b,c
}
```

adding a member to A would make the code not compile anymore...

note that relying on A's sizeof as already suggested could break the code when changing compiler ( this is bad assuming your functions depending on A ( like your serialization code ) happens to be portable )

moreover, the error would tell you that *something* is wrong, whereas this solution would also tell you *where* is wrong ...

the only downside I see being that it relies on a programmer convention ( but, assuming A to be a growing only POD is also a convention anyway ... )

Comment: Another down side is if you switch the order of a, b or c in the struct, you end up tying to the wrong members.

Comment: @bpeikes yep, that's part of the 'convention' ... indeed if I were you I'd put up some compile time pod versioning logic instead of reling on whatever trick comes up here :) ...

Answer (score 1):

In c++11, you can do full reflection of default-aligned AggregateTypes if they're DefaultConstructible (note[1]); construct-only reflection id non-DC. This will be tricky, but the sketch is not that hard (credits: magic_get).

1. Observe that these types have a ctor that has all the types of the class and there's no other ctor taking more params. Hence, you can write:

---

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
using constructed_from = decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())...});
```

2. You can write (thanks, Antony)

---

```
template<size_t i>
struct Ubiq {
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const; /* undef'd */
};
```

3. Read the doc and examples of is_detected if you're not familiar with it: it allows you to detect if an expression is valid. Here you'll test if T is constructible from N Ubiq instances, i.e., if it has at least N params.

At this point, you're ready: you just need to check if it's constructible from your expected types, but not from your types and an Ubiq.

If you want full reflection, you add a `constexpr size_t ctor_param_cnt()`, then you implement a `visit_ctor()` that takes a `template<typename T, size_t i> struct Generator;` which will generate each field via `operator FieldType() const`(which is usually a template). For read access, you need to store field offsets [1].

[1] Note that this requires an ABI where layout of a struct depends only on types in it. Itanium ABI satisfies it.

---

Example (for your use case):

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct S1 {
    int i;
    std::string j;
};

struct S2 {
    int i;
    std::string j;
    int k;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
using constructed_from =
    typename std::decay<decltype(
                T{ std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())... }
             )>::type;

template<size_t i>
struct Ubiq {
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const; /* undef'd */
};

template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

template<typename T, typename AlwaysVoid, typename... Args>
struct is_constructible_from : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct is_constructible_from<T, void_t<constructed_from<T, Args...>>, Args...> : std::true_type {};

static_assert( is_constructible_from<S1, void, int, std::string>::value, "");
static_assert(!is_constructible_from<S1, void, int, std::string, Ubiq<0>>::value, ""); // note: !

static_assert( is_constructible_from<S2, void, int, std::string>::value, "");
static_assert( is_constructible_from<S2, void, int, std::string, Ubiq<0>>::value, ""); // note: no !
```

Comment: wow I missed that, amazing ! ( I haven't upvoted just because you didn't put ( or at least pointed to ) some real code applicable to the OP question; can you add a link to Antony's library ? )

Comment: https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get but two notes: 1. Antony's lib is in c++14 (easy to backport as per above); 2. you'll want to roll your own because his version needs (a minimal amount of) explicit description of each type that can possibly be a field. OTOH, his code is std even for read, mine is std for construct/verify, Itanium ABI for read.